# Spring Boot Thymeleaf - How to use same data in two different fragments?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot 3 application with Thymeleaf in the front end. The page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" th:lang="en" lang="en">

<!-- Head-->
<head th:replace="~{fragments/head :: head}"></head>

<body>

  <div th:if="${profileSection == 'Profile info'}">
      <div th:replace="~{fragments/user/profile-info :: profileInfo}"></div>
  </div>

  <div th:if="${profileSection == 'Downloads'}">
      <div th:replace="~{fragments/user/downloads :: downloads}"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When a user clicks on the profile link, the above page will be rendered with `profileSection == 'Profile info'` so that `fragments/user/profile-info :: profileInfo` will be rendered first and the user details like name, email, phone nr, etc will be rendered. There is a sidebar with let's say 2 links. `Profile info` & `Downloads`.

What I want is this: When a user clicks on the `Download` link from the sidebar, `fragments/user/downloads :: downloads` should be rendered in the middle of the page without fetching downloads from the backend, instead it should use the current `user` object like: `user.getDownloads()` to render the download list. In that way, I don't need to do an extra round to the DB to fetch the user again. The user has a `@ManyToMany` relationship with the Download entity.

How can I do this? Or, is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a User's downloads contain a lot of data, it can consume a lot of memory unnecessarily, as the user may not access the downloads section at all. There is a better approach to this problem.

To start, make sure the `@ManyToMany` relation has `FetchType.LAZY` (which is the default setting, so you should be fine if you haven't specified `FetchType.EAGER` explicitly). This way, the memory won't be filled up unless the user specifically requests the downloads.

When the user clicks on the `Downloads` link in the sidebar, you should have a code like this in the HTML file:

```
<a th:href="@{/user/downloads}">Downloads</a>
```

In the Controller class, you can have something like:

```
@GetMapping("/user/downloads")
public String getDownloads(@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "user") User user, Model model) {
    user.getDownloads().size(); // Now you have access to downloads
    model.addAttribute("profileSection", "Downloads");
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "user/profile-page";
}
```

Make sure to import the AuthenticationPrincipal annotation:

```
org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal
```

Do not use this one, it's deprecated:

```
org.springframework.security.web.bind.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal
```

Spring Boot provides the logged-in user in your Controller method, so just add the user object to the model, and inside the `fragments/user/downloads :: downloads` fragment, you can do something like below snippet to loop through the user's download list:

```
<div th:each="download : ${user.downloads}">
   ...
</div>
```

Note: Be careful if you are using Lombok. The `@Data` / `@Getter` annotations can cause lazy items to load without an explicit call.